# Yocto load kernel module

Tags: module, kernel, yocto

I try to add a kernel module to a yocto image and load it on boot.

I create a recipe to build and install a kernel module. Here's a part of the Makefile content:

```
modules_install: test_driver.ko
    install -d $(MODULES_DIR)
    install -m 0755 $< $(MODULES_DIR)
```

In my *build/conf/local.conf*, I add the package (subsystem being the name of my module recipe):

`IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " subsystem"`

After building the image, I can find the .ko file inside the MODULES_DIR directory (being `/lib/modules/(shell uname -r)/kernel/drivers/test`).

I want to do now is to load this module on boot. I found some clues about `KERNEL_MODULE_AUTOLOAD` and `MACHINE_ESSENTIAL_*/MACHINE_EXTRA_*`.
So I try `KERNEL_MODULE_AUTOLOAD += "subsystem"` or even `KERNEL_MODULE_AUTOLOAD += "test_driver"` in `build/conf/local.conf` or in my module recipe, but I couldn't have the driver loaded on boot.

I'm working against the **fsl-image-machine-test** image (sumo version).

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you have to set those settings in the machine config file and not the local.conf.  @see: https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#incorporating-out-of-tree-modules

Comment: @vermaete indeed ! By using it in my module recipe, it work now (I had also mispelling the KERNEL_MODULE_AUTOLOAD in my file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The KERNEL_MODULE_AUTOLOAD need to be outside of the local.conf file. I put it now in my module recipe.

It needs to load the name of the module not the recipe, in my case :

`KERNEL_MODULE_AUTOLOAD += "test_driver"`.