# Linux won't autoload kernel module

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, kernel-module

I created a basic kernel module that I plan to use eventually for a timing analysis. I am running a v4.14.149 mainline kernel and am building it with Yocto Zeus running on an i.MX6 target. I can't seem to get it to launch automatically.

Everything compiles fine, and I see my *testmodule.ko* show up in */lib/modules/4.14.149/extras/* on target. I can load it and unload it just fine with `insmod` and `rmmod` so I am pretty sure the module is OK. I also see a *testmodule.conf* file that contains the module name (testmodule) in */etc/modules-load.d/* but when I boot and do a `lsmod` I don't see it loaded. I also don't see any output in `journalctl` that would indicate that it loaded.

I have looked at and tried [Yocto: Adding kernel module recipe to image, but it doesn't load on boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36188472/yocto-adding-kernel-module-recipe-to-image-but-it-doesnt-load-on-boot?rq=1) and [Yocto load kernel module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59629344/yocto-load-kernel-module) and have added `KERNEL_MODULE_AUTOLOAD += "testmodule"` in my machine configuration and I also tried it in the module recipe to no avail. I am including the module in my image recipe via `IMAGE_INSTALL_append` as *kernel-module-test*.

Here is the recipe for my module:

```make
SUMMARY = "Test kernel module"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

inherit module

SRC_URI = "file://Makefile \ 
           file://testmodule.c"

S = "${WORKDIR}"

KERNEL_MODULE_AUTOLOAD += "testmodule"

RPROVIDES_${PN} += "kernel-module-test"
```

The module code at the moment just prints a message (it was a sample from a Yocto book I had) and that is it:

```c
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
 
/*
** Module Init function
*/
static int hello_world_init(void)
{
    printk("Markem Kernel Module Inserted Successfully...\n");
    return 0;
}
/*
** Module Exit function
*/
static void hello_world_exit(void)
{
    printk("Markem Kernel Module Removed Successfully...\n");
}

module_init(hello_world_init);
module_exit(hello_world_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("Proprietary");

/*
MODULE_VERSION("0.1");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("A test module.");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Markem-Imaje Corporation");
*/
```

And lastly the *Makefile*, which is also based on the Yocto Book sample

```make
obj-m := testmodule.o

SRC := $(shell pwd)

all:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNEL_SRC) M=$(SRC)

modules_install:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNEL_SRC) M=$(SRC) modules_install

clean:
    rm -f *.o *~ core .depend .*.cmd *.ko *.mod.c
    rm -f Module.markers Module.symvers modules.order
    rm -rf .tmp_versions Modules.symvers
```

If you need the recipe for my kernel or my machine conf or anything, I can get those. Everything I have read indicates that having the file in */etc/modules-load.d/* indicates it should load automatically. Is there possibly a kernel configuration I am missing or something?

Comment: Don't you see the messages in `dmesg`? Otherwise your module is not for a device which means somebody must to load it. There are 2 options basically: a) compile into the kernel, b) use user space tools to make it happen (e.g. `insmod`).

Comment: I don't see any of the print statements in `dmesg`.  It isn't intended to be a device driver.  Are drivers the only modules that can be automatically loaded?